# Where does mbf come from and what's its relation to boldsymbol

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Where does `\mbf` come from and what is its relation to boldsymbol?

Background: It seems that in mtpro2   `\mathbf` does not work for many greek symbols and `\mbf`  is recommended in some instances.  I have always used `\boldsymbol` to get italic bold and `\mathbf` for upright bold.  the command `\mbf` is new to me and seems specific to mtpro2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `\mbf` is defined only by `mtpro2` AFAIK. Again, `\mathbf` does not generate “math bold face”. Instead, `\mathbf` generates “text bold face while in math mode”. If you say `$\mathbf{fi}$` versus `$\mbf{fi}$`, the former will have the usual ligature while the latter behaves as “**f** times **i**”. This is more apparent if you set your text font to, say, Latin Modern, while using MathTime Pro 2 for math.

The `\boldsymbol` command is provided by the AMS bundle (`amsbsy`, to be more specific) to access math bolditalic face. The `amsbsy` manual states, just below the first paragraph, that

> Note: It is recommended nowadays to use the `bm` package, which became available in 1997.

So, please consider using `\usepackage{bm}` and then `\bm{...}` instead.

However, the complete version of `mtpro2` already provides its own command, `\mathbold`, to access its (non-free) math bolditalic. Neither `bm` nor `amsbsy` is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mtpro2} % complete version for access to math bolditalic
\begin{document}
\showoutput
$\mathbf{fi}$ (Latin Modern Bold) versus
$\mbf{fi}$ (MathTime Pro~2 Bold)\par
Use \verb|\mbf| for math variables that are set
in ``bold upright'' form.\par
MathTime Pro~2 ``complete'' defines \verb|\mathbold|:
$\mathbold{fi}$, no need for \verb|\boldsymbol|.
\end{document}
```

> [image: mathbf versus mbf versus mathbold]

### Addendum

To accommodate portability, I’d recommend using the `\mbf`+`\bm` combo throughout your document. Your preamble could look like this:

```
% Use \mbf for bold upright, \bm for bold italic

% Your fonts
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{bm}

% Your collaborator's fonts
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{bm}

% Your other collaborator's fonts
%\usepackage{unicode-math}

...

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  % For non-mtpro2 users, switch \mbf to \mathbf
  \@ifpackageloaded{mtpro2}{}{\let\mbf\mathbf}%
  % For unicode-math users, switch \bm to \symbf
  \@ifpackageloaded{unicode-math}{\let\bm\symbf}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Very informative. So I should actually use `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`? Yes I have the paid version of `mtpro2`. It is quite annoying that  `mtpro2` then has its own definition with `\mathbold`, which then requires a rewrite if you want to test a different math font.

Comment: @mu7z My recommendation is the `\mbf`+`\bm` combo. I’ve added some discussion on portability of your document with your collaborator(s).

Comment: Fantastic recommendation, many thanks.

Comment: However, why even use `bm` instead of `mathbold` ? My tests shows that `mathbold` has better aligning and spacing than using `bm`

Comment: @mu7z `\bm` works also with the lite `mtpro2` (by producing the so-called poor man’s bold) and with other math font packages (the traditional ones, not the OpenType ones). Essentially it comes down to personal preference. You can always use the `mtpro2`-exclusive `\mathbold` and later `\let\mathbold\boldsymbol`, say, when you share your documents with others.

Comment: @mu7z Also, compare `$\bm{\int f(x) \, dx}$` with `$\mathbold{\int f(x) \, dx}$`, ;)

Comment: Here's my universal solution. It uses \mbf for bold upright math and \mbs for bold italic math. It's short and easy to remember. Thanks for the help@Ruixi

% \mbf bold upright math
% \mbs bold italic math
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  % For mtpro2 users, switch \mathbold to \mbs
  \@ifpackageloaded{mtpro2}{\let\mbs\mathbold}{\let\mbs\bm}
  % For non-mtpro2 users, switch \mbf to \mathbf
  \@ifpackageloaded{mtpro2}{}{\let\mbf\mathbf}
}
\makeatother